# How to check if two functions are equal in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

In trying to traverse a list like this, `'((a + b) + (c + d))`, I'll land on the identifier, `+`, and not know how to verify that it is a plus sign and not some other function like `/` or `*`.

How Do I verify that the plus signs I encounter are in fact plus signs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off. `+` in `(a + b)` are symbols, not functions. This is evident if you ever evaluate `+`, which is a variable, you will be presented the value behind the variable. If you evaluate `'+` which evaluates to a symbol it prints out a symbol.

So your real question is how to check if one symbol is the same as another. A symbol in Scheme is unqiue and thus if two symbols look the same they are the same symbol. You may use `eq?` to check this:

```
(define plus '+)
(eq? plus '+) ; ==> #t
(eq? plus '-) ; ==> #f
```